# Is it Possible to create a Silverlight app in full screen mode?

Tags: silverlight, fullscreen

I develop a silverlight app.

my client wants that the gui will be "not browser experience" as posible.

how can i move to full screen mode (f11 style) automaticlly after the client press the url?

what are the limitation on full screen mode?

how can i create close button that the silverlight app will close the browser?

how can i create button that when the client will press it, it will create shortcut icon on desktop?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do things that aren't possible, for good reason - a malicious app could do these things without your consent.

It's not possible to set the app full-screen automatically, this must be in response to user input. This is covered quite clearly in the documentation - [Full Screen Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You also can't use general keyboard input. (These two restrictions won't apply with a [Trusted Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but unless you administer the client machines you won't want to use that).

I'm sure you won't be able to close the browser or create a shortcut either.

You might want to look into [out of browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) Silverlight applications.